# Tile based collision detection, object falls through tiles

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, game-physics, frame-rate

I am having a problem with collision detection on a tile based level at lower framerates. I have a platform game built in Java with the LibGdx game engine. At a framerate of 60 the game runs fine, but if I try it a 30 FPS the character will fall through tiles when it comes down from a jump.

I figured out that the character moved too fast. I already added something to check if there are any tiles that the character already passed, see "// 1" to "// 1 end" in the comments. I don't think it really helped because the problem still occurs.

Falling through the tiles seems to happen when the character hits corners of tiles, although I am not sure about it. It does not happen on a flat ground. Here is a picture of the problem (left is wrong, right is how it should be):

[image]

Again, the problem only happens at lower framerates. I am not sure what I have to change in my code. What am I missing in my code? Or do I have to use a different algorithm?

Here are the most important parts of the collision detection code. collisionY check collisions on the y-axis, collisionX on the x-axis. CheckTiles(checkX) helps finding the tiles that are should be checked (checkX is true if x-axis is checked, if false y-axis is checked):

```
protected boolean collisionY(Rectangle rect) {
    int[] bounds = checkTiles(false);
    Array<Rectangle> tiles = world.getTiles(bounds[0], bounds[1], bounds[2], bounds[3]);
    rect.y += velocity.y;
    if(velocity.y < 0 ) {
        grounded = false;
    }
    for (Rectangle tile : tiles) {
        if (rect.overlaps(tile)) {
            if (velocity.y > 0) {
                this.setY(tile.y - this.getHeight());
            }
            else {
                // 1 Check if there are tiles above
                Rectangle r = null;
                int i = 1;
                Rectangle r1 = null;
                do {
                    r1 = r;
                    r = world.getTile(tile.x, tile.y + i);
                    i++;
                } while (r != null);
                if(r1 != null) {
                    this.setY(r1.y + r1.height);
                }
                // 1 end
                else {
                    this.setY(tile.y + tile.height);
                }
                hitGround();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}

protected boolean collisionX(Rectangle rect) {
    int[] bounds = checkTiles(true);
    Array<Rectangle> tiles = world.getTiles(bounds[0], bounds[1], bounds[2], bounds[3]);
    rect.x += velocity.x;
    for (Rectangle tile : tiles) {
        if (rect.overlaps(tile)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


protected int[] checkTiles(boolean checkX) {
    int startX, startY, endX, endY;
    if(checkX) {
        if (velocity.x > 0) {
            startX = endX = (int) (this.getX() + this.getWidth() + velocity.x);
        }
        else {
            startX = endX = (int) (this.getX() + velocity.x);
        }
        startY = (int) (this.getY());
        endY = (int) (this.getY() + this.getHeight());
    }
    else {
        if (velocity.y > 0) {
            startY = endY = (int) (this.getY() + this.getHeight() + velocity.y); //
        }
        else {
            startY = endY = (int) (this.getY() + velocity.y);
        }
        startX = (int) (this.getX());
        endX = (int) (this.getX() + this.getWidth());
    }
    return new int[]{startX, startY, endX, endY};
}
```

Comment: Do you never use the delta value? It's obtainable by calling Gdx.app.getDeltaTime(). This delta time is a float value representing the amount of time the last frame took to render. This way, you can make sure the speed of your entities are constant from one system to another, not making a fast computer having advantage.

Comment: Yes, I use it. The speed is the same at different FPS.

Answer (score 2):

The "Check if tile above" code will only be run if A) `rect.overlaps(tile)` was `true`, and B) `velocity.y > 0` was `false`. I suspect in the case you care about, this code is simply not being executed. The character is either not overlapping the tile, so the check for tiles above doesn't occur, or its velocity is not such that the check occurs. However, I don't completely understand how the velocity works (how do up and down correspond to positive and negative values?) and I'm not familiar with this game engine.

I would try a different approach, though. Instead of first moving the character (which is what I think the line `rect.y += velocity.y;` does), and then trying to check if it has gone too far or passed through a tile, I would take the direction in which it's moving (`velocity.y`) and look for the *first tile that it would hit going that way*. If there is one, then place the character on that tile. If there's nothing in its way for `velocity.y` units in that direction, then it gets to move the whole distance in this time slice.

Comment: A negative velicity means down, positive up.  'rect', is a copy of the current rectangle of the character, so when it is changed the actual position will not be changed. It is only used for the collision detection. If collisionX returns false the velocity.x is set to 0, same for collisionY.

The position of the character gets set after the collision detection methods.

Comment: Ah, I see. I still think it might be better to do the collision detection by looking ahead to see what the character will hit, if anything, rather than calculating the new y and checking if it has collided, but I could be wrong.